# Modal doesn't fit screen in Chakra UI

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I am doing a project with Next.js and I've been trying to implement this modal on the page using Chakra UI, but it doesn't fit well as you can see in the image below.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Ftu.jpg)

How can I fix that?

Here's the code:

```
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
const sizes = ['sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl', 'full'];
const [size, setSize] = useState('md');
const handleSizeClick = (newSize) => {
    setSize(newSize);
    onOpen();
};

<Modal onClose={onClose}
       size={size}
       isOpen={isOpen}
>
    <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
            <ModalHeader>Entre</ModalHeader>
            <ModalCloseButton />
            <ModalBody>
            </ModalBody>
            <ModalFooter>
                <Button onClick={onClose}>Entrar</Button>
            </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
</Modal>
```

The modal is triggered by an onClick() event in a button within the dropdown menu.

Comment: hey, have you found the solution to this problem? I am facing this problem now.

Comment: I am afraid not, @Nithur.

Comment: Ok, I think it's problem on the chakra side, on later version it is resolved.